# Dynamic Link Problem in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dynamic-linking

I have a program that I'm trying to run, but it gives me this error message:

```
./randomgrowth: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenMeshCore.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file libOpenMeshCore.so.3.3 is in the same folder as randomgrowth and appears to be compiled with the same architecture.

```
file libOpenMeshCore.so.3.3 
libOpenMeshCore.so.3.3: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xa667b49dfa84b046d03db61729274cad7e0b1c39, not stripped
file randomgrowth
randomgrowth: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xeb1031feb0013589b9ae3c5e5a234b15766ea2b9, not stripped
```

Pretty stumped on this one. Any idea what could be wrong?